# JQUERY, Calling a Dialog that I created? Not finding it

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using the following code to create a Dialog box using JQUERY/UI:

```
var $dialog2 = $('<div id="sharerdialog2"></div>')
.html('<p>Loading...</p>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Image Stuffer',
    position: ['center',150],
    width: 450,
    focus:function(event, ui) {
        $('#dialogcloser').click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('close');
        });
    }, 
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $("#sharerdialog2").load("MyURL.com");
    }
});
```

I'm trying to call the Dialog to have it open, but JQUERY isn't finding it using the following:

```
$dialog2.dialog('open');
```

Strangely, if I add the following after the above, it does work on a BIND:

```
$('#ttttt').click(function() {
$dialog2.dialog('open');
});
```

Any ideas why this is? How can I call the Dialog to open in another function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your code in a domready event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $dialog2.dialog('open');

});
```

Comment: I think you have to wrap all of the code in the ready handler.

Comment: That's not necessary. The other code doesn't manipulate the DOM. It simply creates an object ready to be inserted in the DOM later on